# CSS3 Flip animation does not preserve a 3D rotation in Firefox

Tags: css, webkit, transform, transition

I have set up a FLIP animation that uses CSS3 transform property using transitions to create a panel that flips on the Y access as a show and hide effect.

EXAMPLE
http://jsfiddle.net/L9wDd/84/

The transition looks beauutiful in Chrome and Safari (Ie. with -webkit-) however on -moz it the animation is not 3 dimensional. It still works but lacks that 3 dimentional flip that could be seen on -webkit-. What's missing:

```
.container {
    position:relative; display:block;
    -webkit-perspective:1000; -moz-perspective:1000; perspective:1000;
}
.panel {
    margin:50px 100px 50px 100px; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:300px; height:300px; background:blue; border:5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3); border-radius:20px; padding:20px; color:#FFF; box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); display:block; z-index:1; opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition:all 1.2s; -moz-transition:all 1.2s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; -moz-backface-visibility:hidden; 
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.panel.shown {
    opacity:1; z-index:2;
   -webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg); -moz-transform:rotateY(0deg);
}
.panel.seen {
    opacity:0; z-index:1;
   -webkit-transform:rotateY(-180deg); -moz-transform:rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

Comment: Perspective values must be specified with a unit of length, such as `px` or `em`.

Answer (score 0):

The 3D nation of the transition relies on the CSS3 property perspective. This property is currently only supported in -webkit-.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp